# C++ Execute a function through cmd or shell

Tags: c++

First thing,sorry my bad english and any mistakes in asking.
I've searched it a lot,but i was not able to explain in simple words.
I work with Linux servers and command line, i'm used to calling programs through it like

```
./program foo -u adm -p 123
```

But i always wondered how make programs to act like that,i mean call a specific function and write parameters without needing to open program itself.

In other words.

If i code a C++ like that,and compile

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void SayHello(string Name)
 {
     cout << " Hello " << Name;
 }
```

how can i call it through the command line like

```
./Program SayHello CARLOS
```

Sorry about my ignorance,but it's something that i want to learn.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Use main, check http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: I'm assuming you actually want something like "./SayHello Carlos" which outputs "Hello Carlos"?

Comment: Yes , Thanks for your help. I read the site and it helped to understand. :)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Do not add wrong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function of your program based on the arguments, you could do something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    if(argc > 2){
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "SayHello") == 0){
            SayHello(argv[2]);
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Of course this is just a sketch and i can be improved if what you want to achieve is more complex.
You could also build a more dynamic solution if you want other functions than the "SayHello" one to be callable too.

Comment: In other (more) words, there is no link at all between function names in the C or C++ code and anything you do with it as "string".

Comment: Thank you friend, i understand now.It was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Tht is C++; you should use the features the languages provides.

Answer (score 0):

int main( int argc, char** argv )

Here argc refers to the number of argument (arg count)
argv refers to the argument array ("char*" array) (arg value)

Calling your program from command line will result in a main entry with these parameters ; it remains to parse them and launch the command accordingly.

Comment: Please format your answer properly. There is a reason for markup. That is just ugly.

Answer (score -1):

```
void main() {
char *name[] = {
    "./program",
    "-c",
    "foo -u adm -p 123",
    NULL
};
execvp(name[0], name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,it will be useful

Comment: For a starter: `main` has a wrong signature. The array points to string literas which are constant, but is not `const ...` and does not answer the question either.

Comment: @olaf agree with the first 2 statements but didn't OP ask about a program "./program" running specific function "foo" and "write parameters -u adm -p 123" ?

Comment: See the question. The part "... without needing to open program itself." obviously means without re-compilation.

Comment: @olaf  OP says he is "used to calling programs through like: ./program foo -u adm -p 123", that's what I did - call a "./program", and OP said that my example "will be useful"

Answer (score -2):

There you go every executable needs a main function which is the entry point for execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void SayHello(string Name)
{
    cout << " Hello " << Name;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

   if (argc > 1) 
      SayHello(argv[1]);

}
```

To compile this do

> $g++ hello.cpp

It should produce a.out on Linux.

To run it

> ./a.out "World!"

Comment: I think he wants "world!" to be a char* passed in to main.

Comment: Okay I just changed my program to pass in "World!"

Comment: For more sophisticated ways to pass command line options to programs see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: That does not even compile. You don't declare `argv` and don't even check if it is valid, invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: I corrected it so that it compiles. I pasted the wrong version by mistake.